# Cucumber Tagging with Multiple Examples tables in a Scenario Outline

Tags: java, cucumber

In my Cucumber Scenario Outline, some of the examples in my examples table are passing, and some are failing.

I am trying to add tags to these, so I can run those which pass, & skip those which are failing currently.

I have tried to copy some examples I've found online, but I am getting an error.

Below is my latest attempt:

```
    Scenario Outline: BR001 test
    Given...
    When...
    Then...

    @passing
    Examples:
    |     errorCode    |
    |      BRS002      |
    |      BRS003      |
    |      BRS004      |
    |      BRS005      |
    |      BRS008      |
    |      BRS010      |
    |      DE19716     |
    |      BRS006      |
    |      BRS009      |

    @failing
    Examples:                               
    |     errorCode     |
    |       DE19716     |
    |       BRS006      |
    |       BRS009      |
```

But, there is an error with *@passing*. Here is the error message appearing:

> mismatched input '@passing' expecting 'Examples:'

I've copied an online example, so I don't know why this is throwing an error?

Comment: Which version of cucumber are you using? Which online example have you followed?

Comment: Sidenote: the easiest way for me to skip failing ones is to just comment them out. Not proper usage, but will work in a pinch.

Comment: Where is this '@test1' annotation mentioned in the feature file?

Comment: @Marit My version of cucumber in build.gradle is 3.0.2. This is the example I've been following: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/305. Also, I've been commenting them out also, but I've been asked to implement this tagging now, rather than commenting them out

Comment: @Grasshopper Apologies, that was a typo. It actually references **@passing**

Comment: @user9847788 What is the cucumber version?

Comment: @Grasshopper 3.0.2

Comment: @user9847788 This technique works on 3.0.2. Just tried it to confirm. You can look at this post similar to this. Maybe this helps. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131538/execute-only-specific-examples-in-a-scenario-outline/40131705#40131705

Comment: @user9847788 Why are the columns of the two tables different?

Comment: @Grasshopper I've looked at that question you posted. It matches mine, but the error message mentioned in my question is still appearing. Also, I've fixed the column names in my code, they should match

Comment: @user9847788 I copied the scenario in the question and it works perfectly. Added dummy steps for given etc. Maybe ur IDE is adding some extraneous characters. Try writing this in a notepad instead of IDE.

Comment: @Grasshopper It's also not allowing me to add 2 examples tables to a scenario outline. When I add the second Examples table, the second `Examples:` header is underlined, and te error message is **Missing EOF at Examples:**

Comment: Which IDE are u using? Anyways errors in feature file highlighted by IDE does not matter. Just ignore them...

Comment: @Grasshopper Eclipse

Comment: Works for me on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check again your dependencies.

assume following structure

```
src/test/java/features/userdata.feature
src/test/java/glue/StepPojo.java
src/test/java/myRunner/TestRunner.java
pom.xml
```

**pom.xml** dependendencies

```
<properties>
    <version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**userdate.feature** - amended the `Scenario Outline` for the example

Scenario Outline: BR001 test
    Given something
    When happen
    Then result ""

... your both tagged 'Examples:' sections

**StepPojo.java**

package glue;

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepPojo {

    @Given("^something$")
    public void something() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("something");
    }

    @When("^happen$")
    public void happen() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("happen");
    }

    @Then("^result$")
    public void result() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("result");
    }

    @Then("^result \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void result(String errorCode) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("result = " + errorCode);
    }
}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features/userdata.feature",
        glue = {"glue"},
        tags = {"@failing"}
)
public class TestRunner {

}
```

output of `mvn test`

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running myRunner.TestRunner
something
happen
result = DE19716
something
happen
result = BRS006
something
happen
result = BRS009

3 Scenarios (3 passed)
9 Steps (9 passed)
```