# How to execute only few random Examples for Scenario Outline?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

Scenario Outline: Login to the FaceBook

```
Given Enter "<emailId>"

And Enter the "<password>"

When Click on Login button

Then Navigated to HomePage
```

Examples:

**| emailId   | password |**

|abc@***.com| abcd     |

|123@***.com| 1234     |

|@#$@***.com| !@#$     |

-> i want to execute the testcase with "123@***.com" only. How can we achieve this?

When i am putting 2 Examples, i am getting an compilation error "missing EOF at 'Examples:'" in the 2nd Examples.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can have different `Examples` sections each with a different `tag`. Then you can run only the examples with a specific tag. An example can be found in this [SO post - cucumber-tagging-with-multiple-examples-tables-in-a-scenario-outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041171/cucumber-tagging-with-multiple-examples-tables-in-a-scenario-outline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the execution of succeeding steps using a flag. Scenario Outline: Create

```
Given Enter "<emailId>"
And Enter Password "<password>"
And Check "<runFlag>"
When Click on Login button
Then Navigated to HomePage

Examples: 
  | emailId         | password | runFlag  |
  | abc@***.com     |     abcd | N        |
  | 123@***.com     |     1234 | Y        |
  | @#$@***.com     |     !@#$ | N        |
```

Then create your own logic using the flag variable to control the execution flow and assertion of upcoming steps

```
private static String flag;

    @Given("^Enter \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter(String username) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("=============================================================");
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);
    }

    @Given("^Enter Password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter_p(String password) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
    }

    @Given("^Check \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void check(String runFlag) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Run Flag: " + runFlag);
        flag = runFlag;
    }

    @When("^Click on Login button$")
    public void click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
        if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(flag)){
            System.out.println("Clicked Login");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Skipped: RunFlag=" + flag);
        }
    }

    @Then("^Navigated to HomePage$")
    public void navigated_to_HomePage() throws Throwable {
        if("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(flag)){
            System.out.println("Navigated to homepage");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Skipped: RunFlag=" + flag);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should nail the OP.